# Composing partial getters using the lens library

Tags: haskell, lenses

I am using the lens package and and keep thinking there must be an easy solution to the following problem. Say I have some map (or any `At` instance) and a lens on its value type, ie

```
aMap :: Map Int a
aLens :: Simple Lens a b
```

I want a getter

```
g :: Getter (Map Int a) (Maybe b)
```

This is because I often want to do something like this

```
x :: Maybe b
x = aMap^.at 3.g.aLens
```

The intended semantics of course being that you get a `Just` value when you do so in the `at` lookup and `Nothing` otherwise.

When one is setting instead of getting `traverse` works in place of `g`, ie

```
newMap = at 3.traverse.aLens .~ whatever $ aMap
```

but not when you are getting. Is there some ready built in lens the library that I have simply missed, or is there another simple way of achieving this in a single expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been running into a similar problem trying to compose lenses with `at`.

If you don't need the insertion/deletion behavior of `at` here, what about using `ix`?

```
x :: Maybe b
x = aMap ^? ix 3 . aLens
```

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to come up with

```
x :: Maybe b
x = aMap^.at 3 <&> (^.aLens)
```

which is a little confusing and not *exactly* what I was looking for, but gets the job done.